# «Хотя, может быть, они и справедливы». Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, частицы

*Хотя, может быть, они и справедливы.*

Интересно, к какой части предложения относится "хотя" —  к вводной конструкции или к основной части? Стоит ли отделять запятой эту частицу? В данном случае это частица?

Comment: Дополнение к ответу: Союз "хотя" не может относится к вводным оборотам, в отличие от союза "а", который может образовывать связку. Но "может быть" по задумке автора может и выступать сказуемым (не являться вводным).

Answer (score 1):

Здесь возможны 2 варианта:

"Может быть" - не вводное словосочетание, "хотя" относится к "может быть", без запятой.
*Хотя может быть, (что) они и справедливы.*

"Может быть" - вводное словосочетание, "хотя" относится к "они и справедливы", с запятой.
*Хотя, может быть, они и справедливы.*

В данных вариантах "хотя" - это союз, согласно словарю БТС Кузнецова.

Answer (score 1):

Куда относится "хотя", решает автор — и ставит соответствующую пунктуацию.

Разница следующая:
*Хотя, может быть, они и справедл**И**вы. = Хотя они, может быть, и справедливы. = **Хотя, может, они и справедливы.*** || После "хотя" есть пауза при чтении, фразовое ударение не падает на вводный оборот.
*Хотя может б**Ы**ть, они и справедл**И**вы. = Хотя может быть так, что они и справедливы.* || Фразовое ударение падает на слово "быть".